# How to route to a controller method in Laravel Moduler development?

Tags: laravel, module, namespaces, laravel-routing

I am using `"artem-schander/l5-modular": "dev-master"` for laravel moduler development.

For example i create an Admin module.

Folder structure is App/Modules/Admin.

So **controller** related to **Admin modules** placed under **App/Modules/Admin/Controllers/** directory.

All **routes** related to **Admin module** are placed in **App/Modules/Admin/routes.php** file.

Here how it looks

```
Route::group(array('module' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['web'],'namespace' => 'App\Modules\Admin\Controllers'), function() {

    Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');

});
```

All view files related to admin module placed in App/Modules/Admin/Views folder.

I am trying to access Admin's index view using this route

```
Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');
```

This route is place in laravel default routes.php file.

and when i browse ,I am getting this error

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\AdminController does not exist
```

From this i understood , laravel looking AdminController in its default path.

How can i overcome this challenge ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two way to do it.

**First Option**

Changing the **$namespace**  in **RouteServiceProvider.php** .

For me

`private $namespace='\App\Modules';`

So for Admin module i can use route as

```
Route::get('/', 'Admin\Controllers\AdminController@index');
```

I think this is bad idea to change Laravel's default value.

**Second Option**

Providing full path of the Controller.

So route would be like this

```
Route::get('/','\App\Modules\Admin\Controllers\AdminController@index');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access a controller by full qualified namespace if it is not in default path.

Try:

```
Route::resource('admin', '\App\Modules\Admin\Controllers\AdminController');
```